# setup.py: how to find user-specified bracketed extras

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, pypi, python-packaging

I have a package that is distributed via PyPI that includes a lot of data.  PyPI has a 100Mbyte limit and I want to distribute more data than that.  The data is pretty invariant so it also seems wasteful to keep pushing a big chunk of data to PyPI with every code release.

Instead I would prefer to distribute minimal data, and have the big data option handled as an optional sub package, e.g. `pip install mypackage[lotsofdata]`.  This would be specified by an `extras_require` argument to `setup()` in `setup.py`.  The actual data load would be a post-install action in `setup.py` which pulls the data down from a server using `wget` or something similar.

I know how to do post-install actions

```
from setuptools.command.install import install

class InstallWrapper(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        # post install stuff goes here
        #  if [lotsofdata] option given, install it from server
```

but I don't know how to get access to the user's command line to see whether the option `[lotsofdata]` was given.

Does anybody know how to get this info from the install-time code?

`self` is an instance of a `setuptools.command.install` class which inherits from `distils.command.install` which inherits from `distils.cmd.Command`.  There's no obvious method or attribute that will give me what I'm looking for, but the code and documentation is not so easy to follow.

These bracket arguments seem to have inconsistent naming such "setuptools extras", "install extras", "package extras".  The term "extra" seems to have lots of meanings within the whole setuptools/distutils world.

Comment: What you seem to be trying to do does not look like a good practice to me. It seems like you are trying to override the behavior of _extras_, I would recommend against it. -- How much data are we really talking about here? Are we slightly above the 100MB limit or largely above it?

Comment: @sinoroc much above.  Happy for your ideas about alternative solutions that are convenient for the user.

Comment: 1. You can't get access to extras in the `distutils` commands, they are resolved by the package manager (`pip`, `easy_install` etc) and 2. `InstallWrapper` won't be executed on e.g. `pip install` in most situations. If you need to install additional optional data, implement it in your tool itself and document the steps in the docs.

Comment: You can also create another package that contains the data, upload it to PyPI once and depend on it via extras in your main package. Regarding size issue, you can [file a new limit request](https://github.com/pypa/pypi-support/issues/new?assignees=&labels=limit+request&template=limit-request.md&title=Limit+Request%3A+PROJECT_NAME+-+000+MB) - if you don't have gigabytes of data you need to upload and you don't upload multiple versions per day, there are good chances you get the green light.

Comment: Yes, either you find an arrangement with PyPI to have an extra package bigger than 100MB. -- Or my recommendation would be to add a run-time "download" command to your tool/library that then stores the result in something like `~/.local/share`. The project ["nltk" does something like that](https://www.nltk.org/data.html). -- Overriding the _setuptools_ commands does not work.